# Limit a specific type of user in Firestore to read documents based on time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Has any way to limit users to read based on time, using Firestore Rules?

E.g: Limit a malicious user authenticated as an anonymous user to read a document several times per millisecond. This can cause elevate pricing for this multiples requests

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to limit the rate of document reads using security rules.  If you think someone is abusing the resources in your project, [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) and explain what you're observing.

Comment: How i know if there user has abusing?  Firestore provides any log to see that?

Comment: It might not be possible, depending on the way you set up your data.  You might have to simply notice a spike in billing,  You should contact Firebase support to get more details about your options.